# Regular expression for IP Address Validation

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to validate the value is valid IP Address or not..!

I Used to validate like

```
ValidIpAddressRegex = "^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$";
```

it's working fine, but when i give the values like `12345678` , its also return **true**..
How to solve this?

Comment: "2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334" isnt a valid IP according to that regex either. IPv6 is the new standard :)

Comment: Just a tip: Many answers answer below utilize `\d` which is more compact than `[0-9]`, but it is more efficient for the regex engine if you use `[0-9]`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738

Comment: As I am sure many people are aware, the 4 octet dotted decimal is not the ONLY valid IPv4 format. Google's 8.8.8.8 server can be reached via octal 0010.0010.0010.0010, hex 0x08.0x08.0x08.0x08 and any number of other formats. Most IPv4 implementations will also accept missing octets as valid. So, 8.8 becomes 8.0.0.8 - yes, really. Lastly, if you're testing for "validity", are you concerned if it's an RFC1918 ("local") address, a multicast or some other probably-not-intended address (e.g. Class C broadcast .255 or network .o)? This discussion may help https://superuser.com/questions/929153

Comment: Please use my answer from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23483855/javascript-regex-to-validate-ipv4-and-ipv6-address-no-hostnames/69685444#69685444, it's the most accurate one so far.

Answer (score 38):

There is a simpler way. You just need to split the string on `.` and check that every number is between 0 and 255.

Additionally, you can check for hexa and split on `:` for IPv6.

---

Just because I think it's funny:

```
^(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))$
```

Here is a regex that should handle IPs (v4).

Comment: They dont have to be humongous. I bet your code is longer then a good regex.

Comment: @TJHeuvel, and yet more performant :). Regexes are a useful tool, but it's a big engine used to do way more complicated tasks, so using one here is like using a bazooka to catch a fly. You'll probably get it done, but at what cost?

Comment: I think this one removes redundancy from your version... `(?<!\S)((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\b|\.\b){7}(?!\S)`

Comment: This is a good example where regular expressions can parse the text but cannot understand the semantic meaning of them. You cant easily tell with a regex that the number has to be between 0 and 255 as it cant understand numbers only text. I would capture the regex with ([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+) and validate it without a regular expression

Comment: how would you prevent the first number from being 0?

Comment: I think the splitting an IPv4 address by . approach lends itself better for testing "meaningful" addresses, such as not RFC1918, not multicast and potentially not Class A/B/C broadcast (e.g. .255) or network (e.g. ,0) addresses. If the aim is validation of user input, not only would you want to protect from malicious input, but also user, er, "ignorance". If someone enters an RFC1918 address (e.g. 192.168.1.2) on a public server, that could be both a security breach (depending how the address is used), but probably also not what the user desired.

Answer (score 19):

Looking for one for IPv4, I ended up just creating it myself. (This only handles the common dotted variant, i.e. 0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255)

```
^                           # START OF STRING
  (?=\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$)     # Lookahead, require this format: number.number.number.number END OF STRING
  (?:                         # Start non-capture group (number 0-255 + optional dot)
    (?:                         # Start non-capture group (number 0-255)
      25[0-5]                     # 250-255
      |                           # OR
      2[0-4][0-9]                 # 200-249
      |                           # OR
      1[0-9]{2}                   # 100-199
      |                           # OR
      [1-9][0-9]                  # 10-99
      |                           # OR
      [0-9]                       # 0-9
    )                           # End non-capture group
    \.?                         # Optional dot (enforced in correct positions by lookahead)
  ){4}                        # End non-capture group (number + optional dot), repeat 4 times
$                           # END OF STRING
```

Without comments:

```
^(?=\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$)(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.?){4}$
```

Some code to test it:

```js
function isValidIpv4Addr(ip) {
  return /^(?=\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$)(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.?){4}$/.test(ip);
}
var testAddr = ['192.68.35.35','0.0.0.0','255.0.0.0','192.168.1.0','192.168.0.1','255.255.255.0','1.1.1.1','255.255.255.255','249.249.249.249','200.200.200.200','199.199.199.199','100.100.100.100','99.99.99.99','0.0.0.0','9.9.9.9','10.10.10.10','99.99.99.99','100.100.100.100','109.109.109.109','110.110.110.110','199.199.199.199','200.200.200.200','249.249.249.249','250.250.250.250','255.255.255.255','256.256.256.260','192.168.0.0/24','192.168..1','192.168.1','1','1.','1.1','1.1.','1.1.1','1.1.1.','1.1.1.1.','1.1.1.1.1','.1.1.1.1','01.01.01.01','09.09.09.09','1.0.0.1.0','010.1.1.1','123456','123123123123','.127.0.0.1'];
for (var i = 0; i < testAddr.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById('ipv4tests').innerHTML += '<li>' + testAddr[i] + ' ' + (isValidIpv4Addr(testAddr[i]) ? '<font color="green">VALID!</font>' : '<font color="red">INVALID!</font>') + '</li>';
}
```

```html
<ul id="ipv4tests"></ul>
```

Comment: Excellent write-up explaining what the regex does.  Here's a regex based on yours that will also match CIDR notation (not perfect, but close enough): `^(?=\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+(\/\d+)?$)(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.?){4}(?:\/(?:[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-2]))?$`

Answer (score 12):

This works properly for all possible cases.

```
^(([1-9]?\d|1\d\d|2[0-5][0-5]|2[0-4]\d)\.){3}([1-9]?\d|1\d\d|2[0-5][0-5]|2[0-4]\d)$
```

Comment: .The 2[0-5][0-5] part can be modified as 25[0-5] since 2[0-4]\d matches  everything from 200 up to 249. A little shorter version of your answer would be                  `^(([1-9]?\d|1\d\d|25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d)\.){3}([1-9]?\d|1\d\d|25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d)$` Great answer, btw.

Comment: I would normally distrust something that claims to work in _all possible cases_.  Did you run infinite tests?  Or derive a mathematical proof?  However, in this case I think this actually is the best solution, and probably does work correctly in all cases :)

Answer (score 7):

I know this is old, but try this one:

```
    /^(?:(?:2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|1\d{2}|[1-9]?\d)\.){3}(?:2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|1\d{2}|[1-9]?\d)(?:\:(?:\d|[1-9]\d{1,3}|[1-5]\d{4}|6[0-4]\d{3}|65[0-4]\d{2}|655[0-2]\d|6553[0-5]))?$/
```

I made it today for a function in php.

It handles ip's from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 and ports from 0 to 65535.

Examples:

```
validates:
    0.0.0.0:0
    255.0.0.0
    192.168.1.0:8080
does not validate:
    192.168.0.0/24
    192.168..1
    192.168.1
```

I know this is a frankenregex, but still, it works!

If port doesn't matter, use this one:

```
    /^(?:(?:2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|1\d{2}|[1-9]?\d)\.){3}(?:2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|1\d{2}|[1-9]?\d)$/
```

Comment: @DavidG You are welcome. Anything you see that can be improved, please, place a comment here.

Comment: Mate, very nice work! Of the four answers that correctly match this test https://regex101.com/r/vX2hK4/14 , yours is the most performant by far! http://jsperf.com/js-regex-ip-address (puts my answer to shame)

Comment: @NickG I never knew that Regex could be **THAT** fast! o.O I would also add the version without port number. I will be testing it on different browsers and systems. And thank you for taking your time to write a testcase.

Answer (score 4):

Try this shortened one:

```
^(([1-9]?\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(\.(?!$)|(?=$))){4}$
```

Here is the test case for this regex:

```js
  function verifyIp(ip)
  {
    return /^(([1-9]?\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(\.(?!$)|(?=$))){4}$/.test(ip||"");
  }
  
  ["192.68.35.35","0.0.0.0","255.0.0.0","192.168.1.0","192.168.0.1","255.255.255.0","1.1.1.1","255.255.255.255","249.249.249.249","200.200.200.200","199.199.199.199","100.100.100.100","99.99.99.99","0.0.0.0","9.9.9.9","10.10.10.10","99.99.99.99","100.100.100.100","109.109.109.109","110.110.110.110","199.199.199.199","200.200.200.200","249.249.249.249","250.250.250.250","255.255.255.255","256.256.256.260","192.168.0.0/24","192.168..1","192.168.1","1","1.","1.1","1.1.","1.1.1","1.1.1.","1.1.1.1.","1.1.1.1.1",".1.1.1.1","01.01.01.01","09.09.09.09","1.0.0.1.0","010.1.1.1","123456","123123123123",".127.0.0.1"].forEach(function(item){
    is_valid = verifyIp(item);
    $('<div>'+item+' <span class="'+(is_valid?'correct':'wrong')+'">'+(is_valid?'VALID':'INVALID')+'</span></div>').appendTo('#result');
  });
```

```css
.item {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.wrong {
  color: red;  
}

.correct {
  color: green;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution:

```
^(([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))\.){3}([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))$
```

Comment: This incorrectly matches zero prefixed numbers `010.1.1.1` - https://regex101.com/r/vX2hK4/12

Answer (score 2):

Just extending on @DavidFaber 's excellent solution. To match an IPv4 "[Dotted decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Address_representations)" notation (no range/ports):

```
^(((1?[1-9]?|10|2[0-4])\d|25[0-5])($|\.(?!$))){4}$
```

**Match examples:** https://regex101.com/r/vX2hK4/15

Code golf anyone?

Comment: This extended solution incorrectly matches `.127.0.0.1`

Comment: Good catch @scentos, solution updated to exclude `.` prefixed addresses.

Comment: including the optional leading zeroes `^((0*)((1?[1-9]?|10|2[0-4])\d|25[0-5])($|\.(?!$))){4}$`

Answer (score 1):

You might also try this:

```
^((?:(?:^|\.)(?:\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){4})$
```

We want the pattern to repeat exactly four times - in this case our pattern is a number in the range of 0 - 255 preceded by either a period `.` or the start of the string! Since the start of the string can occur only once, the other three occurrences must be periods.

[Please see this Regex 101 demo for a full explanation.](https://regex101.com/r/vX2hK4/1)

Comment: Incorrectly matches when there is a leading dot, e.g. `.1.1.1.1`

Comment: @scentos, thanks for the correction. Can add a negative lookeahead to address that: `(?!^\.)`: https://regex101.com/r/vX2hK4/10

Answer (score 1):

This reg ex works well but trust me its an overkill.
To have conditional comparisons like here less then **255** its best to have combination of RegEx and conditionals.

```
^(([0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]{1})|(2?[0-4]?[0-9]{1})|(25[0-5]))\.(([0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]{1})|(2?[0-4]?[0-9]{1})|(25[0-5]))\.(([0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]{1})|(2?[0-4]?[0-9]{1})|(25[0-5]))\.(([0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]{1})|(2?[0-4]?[0-9]{1})|(25[0-5]))$
```

Answer (score 1):

trying to shorten Grealy's version

```
^((1?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])($|\.(?!$))){4}$
```

note: as the previous version this doesn't correctly handle octal numbers, like 0177.0.0.1

Comment: This is the shortest posted solution. I just would change the capturing groups to non-capturing to avoid creating backreferences `^(?:(?:1?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:$|\.(?!$))){4}$`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5293986/1851290

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS,

```
ValidIpAddressRegex = "^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check with my given expressions as well, I had checked and written a program in java to validate the ipv4 address. It returns true if Ipv4 address is correct or vice-versa.

String pattern="^([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$"

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Solution{

    public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(in.hasNext()){
            String IP = in.next();
            System.out.println(IP.matches(new MyRegex().pattern));
        }

    }
}

    class MyRegex{
        String pattern="^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\dCongrats, you solved this challenge!\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Colin Hebert pointed out the best solution. But no one have "explained" by supplying the code for it, so here goes ( "Just because I think it's funny:" ;)

```js
var aIP = [
  '192.168.0.1',
  '255.255.255.255',
  '1.2.34.647',
  '256.0.0.0',
  '255,0,0,0',
  '123.123.123',
  '1.2.3.4.5'
  ];

aIP.forEach(function(ipAddr) {
  
  var a = ipAddr.split('.'),
      cnt = 4;

  document.write('Testing ' + ipAddr + '<br/>');

  try {
    a.forEach(function(v) {
      if( v<0 || v>255 )
        throw false;
      cnt--;
    });
    if( cnt!=0 )
        throw false;
      cnt--;
    document.write('- Pass!<br/>');
  }
  catch (e) {
    document.write('- Fail!<br/>');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use this regex to validate any ip address without port number, like this format (192.168.1.1)

```
/^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as well:

```
(((?<![\d])([0-9][\.])|(?<![\d])([1-9][0-9][\.])|(?<![\d])(1[0-9]{2}[\.])|(?<![\d])(2[0-5][0-5][\.]))(([0-9][\.])|([1-9][0-9][\.])|(1[0-9]{2}[\.])|(2[0-5][0-5][\.])){2}(([0-9])(?![\d])|([1-9][0-9])(?![\d])|(1[0-9]{2})(?![\d])|(2[0-5][0-5])(?![\d])))
```

although this is a 5 years old question so I doubt you are still looking for the answer.

posted more info on another thread:
[Validating IPv4 addresses with regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284147/validating-ipv4-addresses-with-regexp/46207649#46207649)

Answer (score 0):

**for the pattern
ex 192.168.23.28/255.255.255.0**

```
^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[1-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-4]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[1-9][0-9]?)\/(((128|192|224|240|248|252|254)\.0\.0\.0)|(255\.(0|128|192|224|240|248|252|254)\.0\.0)|(255\.255\.(0|128|192|224|240|248|252|254)\.0)|(255\.255\.255\.(0|128|192|224|240|248|252|254)))$
```

**for the pattern
ex 192.168.26.82/24 or 192.168.23.28/255.255.255.0**

```
^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[1-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-4]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[1-9][0-9]?)\/([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-2]|(((128|192|224|240|248|252|254)\.0\.0\.0)|(255\.(0|128|192|224|240|248|252|254)\.0\.0)|(255\.255\.(0|128|192|224|240|248|252|254)\.0)|(255\.255\.255\.(0|128|192|224|240|248|252|254))))$
```

**for the pattern
ex 192.168.26.28**

```
^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[1-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-4]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[1-9][0-9]?)$
```

**for the netmask
ex 255.255.255.0**

```
^(((128|192|224|240|248|252|254)\.0\.0\.0)|(255\.(0|128|192|224|240|248|252|254)\.0\.0)|(255\.255\.(0|128|192|224|240|248|252|254)\.0)|(255\.255\.255\.(0|128|192|224|240|248|252|254)))$
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP asked for validation of an IP address. The phrasing of the Q almost certainly implies IPv4 (as opposed to IPv6). I've already commented on the OP about how far that validity checking might go, as well as applauding one responder for taking an non-RE approach. As I also wanted to (under some circumstances) test for validity for the address if I use it on a public server, I came up with the following JS:

```
function isSimpleIPv4( ip, u=true ) {
    if ((ip === undefined) || (ip === null) || (ip.length > 15)) return false;
    var p = ip.split(\'.\');
    if (p.length != 4) return false;
    p.forEach( function(v,k){p[k]=Number(v);} );
    if (isNaN(p[0]) || isNaN(p[1]) || isNaN(p[2]) || isNaN(p[3]) ) return false;
    if ((p[0] < 1) || (p[0] > 255) || (p[1] < 0) || (p[1] > 255) || (p[2] < 0) || (p[2] > 255) || (p[3] < 0) || (p[3] > 255)) return false;
    if (!u) return true;
    if ((p[0] > 223)) return 'multicast';
    if ((p[0] == 127)) return 'loopback';
    if ((p[0] == 10)) return 'RFC1918';
    if ((p[0] == 192) && (p[1] == 168)) return 'RFC1918';
    if ((p[0] == 172) && (p[1] >= 16) && (p[1] <= 31)) return 'RFC1918';
    return true;
}
```

If one wants to check for "useful" addresses, then only the string IP is needed, otherwise, if just checking for 0-255.0-255.0-255.0-255, then call the function with the IP-string and false. In the former case, the function will return true/false/ when  is the "failing" cause of the usefulness. RFC1918 addresses intended by a website visitor won't be reachable from a public server and may even compromise one of one's own servers (as might addresses in the loopback range 127.x.x.x). Equally, using a multicast address is not helpful either. If you're interested in usefulness checking but don't care about the cause, then you'll just need to do `if (isSimpleIPv4(ipString) !== true) console.log('Not a valid and useful IP address');`

Answer (score 0):

IPv4 has 4 blocks of numbers from 0 to 255 that could contain padding zeroes on the left. Each block is spaced with a dot.

Short and simple IPv4 validator:

```
var block "([0-1]{0,1}[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|)";
var ipv4 = "(" + block +"\\.){3}" + block ;
```

Validates any IP Like:

- 000.12.12.034
- 121.234.12.12
- 23.45.12.56
- 003.045.012.056
- 03.45.12.6
- 0.45.122.255

Answer (score 0):

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators }   from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      ipranging="";
      testForm1: FormGroup;
      testForm2: FormGroup;
      constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){

      }
      ngOnInit(): void {
        const ipPattern = 
        "(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)";
        this.testForm1 = this.fb.group({
          inp: ['', Validators.pattern(ipPattern)],
          inp3: ['', Validators.pattern(ipPattern)]
        });
        this.testForm2 = this.fb.group({
          inp: ['', Validators.pattern(ipPattern)],
          inp2: ['', Validators.pattern(ipPattern)],
          inp3: ['', Validators.pattern(ipPattern)]
        });
        this.testForm2.setValidators(this.comparisionValidator);
      }

      public comparisionValidator(group: FormGroup) : any{

        const control1 = group.controls['inp'];
        const control2 = group.controls['inp2'];
        var control1array  = control1.value.split('.');
        var control2array = control2.value.split('.');

        if(parseInt(control1array[0]) > parseInt(control2array[0]) ){
          group.controls['inp3'].setErrors({ 'value2GreaterThanValue1': true });
          console.log(group); 
        }
        else if(parseInt(control1array[1]) > parseInt(control2array[1]) ){
          group.controls['inp3'].setErrors({ 'value2GreaterThanValue1': true });
          console.log(group); 
        }
        else if(parseInt(control1array[2]) > parseInt(control2array[2]) ){
          group.controls['inp3'].setErrors({ 'value2GreaterThanValue1': true });
          console.log(group); 
        }
        else if(parseInt(control1array[3]) > parseInt(control2array[3]) ){
          group.controls['inp3'].setErrors({ 'value2GreaterThanValue1': true });
          console.log(group); 
        }
        else {
          group.controls['inp3'].setErrors({ 'value2GreaterThanValue1': false });
          console.log(group);
        }   
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div style="text-align:left">
        <h2>Choose if you want to enter a single ip or range of ip's</h2>
      <select  [(ngModel)]="ipranging">
        <option  selected disabled value="none"> -- select an option -- </option>
        <option  value='ip'>Single Ip address</option>
        <option  value="range">Ip range</option>
      </select>
      </div>

    <form *ngIf="ipranging === 'ip'" novalidate [formGroup]="testForm1" class="render">
      <label>IP Address: 
        <input formControlName="inp" placeholder='0.0.0.0'/></label>
            <input formControlName="inp3" hidden/>
          <!-- <p *ngIf="testForm.controls.inp.status == 'INVALID' && testForm.controls.inp.value != ''" >Invalid</p>
          <p *ngIf="testForm.controls.inp2.status == 'INVALID' && testForm.controls.inp2.value != ''" >Invalid</p> -->
          <p *ngIf="testForm1.controls.inp.value != '' && testForm1.controls.inp.status == 'INVALID'" >Invalid</p>
    </form>

    <form *ngIf="ipranging === 'range'" novalidate [formGroup]="testForm2" class="render">
      <label>Starting IP:
        <input formControlName="inp" placeholder='0.0.0.0'/></label>
          <label>
              Ending IP:
            <input formControlName="inp2" placeholder='0.0.0.0'/></label>
            <input formControlName="inp3" hidden/>
          <!-- <p *ngIf="testForm.controls.inp.status == 'INVALID' && testForm.controls.inp.value != ''" >Invalid</p>
          <p *ngIf="testForm.controls.inp2.status == 'INVALID' && testForm.controls.inp2.value != ''" >Invalid</p> -->
          <p *ngIf="testForm2.controls.inp.value != '' && testForm2.controls.inp.status == 'INVALID' || testForm2.controls.inp2.value != '' && testForm2.controls.inp2.status == 'INVALID'" >Invalid</p>
          <p *ngIf="testForm2.controls.inp3.errors.value2GreaterThanValue1 == true">Starting IP is larger than the ending IP</p>
    </form>
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/22291567)

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
^(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})$
```

Comment: No mechanism to impose max value of 255