# grep with wildcard symbols

Tags: bash, grep, wildcard

Wildcard search with grep

I have a file that contains many IP addresses. I wanted to list all the ip addresses in the file and I used grep with a pattern 192.16* but it doesn't show the whole list of IP addresses. I am able to list the whole IP addresses only while using period followed with an asterisk symbol. So my doubt is Why 2nd option not working but 3rd option works fine.

```
root@test:~/test# cat z
192.168.1.0
192.168.2.0
192.168.110.7
192.168.115.5

1. root@test:~/test# grep -o 192.1 z
192.1
192.1
192.1
192.1


2. root@test:~/test# grep -o 192.1* z
192.1
192.1
192.1
192.1

3. root@test:~/test# grep -o 192.1. z
192.16
192.16
192.16
192.16


4. root@test:~/test# grep -o 192.1.* z
192.168.1.0
192.168.2.0
192.168.110.7
192.168.115.5
```

Comment: I think you want `grep 192\.1 z`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why your commands are (not) working:**

```
1. root@test:~/test# grep -o 192.1 z
```

Only `192<any char>1` will be matched, and only the matching part will be printed because of the `-o` switch.

```
2. root@test:~/test# grep -o 192.1* z
```

Only `192<any char>`, `192<any char>1`, `192<any char>11`, `192<any char>111` etc. will be matched, and only the matching part will be printed because of the `-o` switch. Your input does not contain data where this makes any difference.

```
3. root@test:~/test# grep -o 192.1. z
```

Only `192<any char>1<any char>` will be matched, and only the matching part will be printed because of the `-o` switch. This gives you one more character (`.` stands for "any" single character).

```
4. root@test:~/test# grep -o 192.1.* z
```

Any line starting with `192<any char>1` will be matched, and only the matching part will be printed because of the `-o` switch. `.*` matches anything up to the end of the line, including the empty string.

**Regular expression for IP addresses**

You can find lots of IP address regular expressions on the web, see for example this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006459/regular-expression-for-ip-address-validation). Note however that some of the expressions are used to match only the IP address and therefore contain beginning- (`^`) and end-of-line (`$`) characters. You will have to remove those if your input contains more than just the addresses.

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation but I am still confused with the second one, you said:

`"Only 192<any char>1, 192<any char>11, 192<any char>111 etc. will be matched"`

but why it cant be :

`"Only 192<any char>1, 192<any char>16, 192<any char>168 etc."` as far as i know, `*` means anything that includes all the IP addresses in the 192.168 region too.

Comment: In (both ["basic" and "extended"](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Basic-vs-Extended.html)) regular expressions, `*` is a quantifier. That means that it denotes, _how often_ the preceding character must be present in the input to match the pattern. `*` stands for `zero or more times`. So in example 2, `1*` means `zero or more "1" characters`. However, I've just noticed that that my answer was not exact about the "zero" part, I've edited that. See manpage `regex(7)` for more info about regular expressions used by `grep`.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating. It  is clear for me now :)

Answer (score 7):

- A dot (`.`) matches *any* character, you have to escape it: `\.`.
- `-o` shows only  the matching part, if you ommit `.*` (= any characters) from the end, it will ommit the rest of the line (as it's not part of the matched string).
- `.*` can match a lot more than you need (it will match the rest of the line), prefer to say explicitly what you allow: `[0-9.]*`.
- Make sure you put the search expression in single quotes `'192.168\.[0-9.]*'`, otherwise the shell will interpret the special characters, and substitute the expression with the matched filenames (luckily you didn't have any matching filenames).
- You might only want to searh for words (`-w`). If you want to make sure you only match IP addresses and not something that resembles to it (no consecutive dots, exactly 4 digits, <=255...) then you'll need a lot more complex expression.