# ng-pattern In Angular JS for IP Address Validation

Tags: javascript, html, regex, angularjs

I am trying to validate IP Address in the text box with ng-pattern

**CODE:**

```
<input name="machinestodiscover" type="text" ng-model="machinestodiscover" ng-minlength="7" ng-maxlength="15" ng-pattern="/\b([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})\b/" required>
 <span ng-show="conditionForm.machinestodiscover.$error.required" class="help-block" style="display:inline;">*Machines To discover Required</span>
 <span ng-show="conditionForm.machinestodiscover.$error.pattern" class="help-block" style="display:inline;">*IP Pattern Wrong.</span>
```

The problem I am facing is that it is even accepting value as 1.1.1.1.1.1.1.

where as I checked the expression in http://regexr.com/

**Screenshots:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

What is wrong in my regex/ng-pattern

Comment: Try regex provided in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006459/regular-expression-for-ip-address-validation

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with `\b` which is word boundary. That is `.` is also matched by the word boundaries.

Use anchors instead,

```
^([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})[.]([0-9]{1,3})$
```

- `^` Anchors the regex at the start of the string.
- `$` Anchors the regex at the end of the string

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/zA8jP0/1)

Comment: Perfect RegEx. Also, to make the IP address validation more robust, range checking for each IPv4 address segment to be done, i.e. to validate that each address segment is between 0 and 255 (both end inclusive)!

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/HBTDi1/1