# Regex golf - Is there a shorter way?

Tags: regex

I've made this regex to check whether a string is a valid IP, including checking if each octel is between 0-255 (more specifically, it checks if it's between 0-199 *OR* 200-249 *OR* 250-255)

`((1?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(1?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])`

A more simple way of looking at it is:

`(pattern\.){3}pattern`

which matches `pattern.pattern.pattern.pattern` such that pattern is a number between 0 and 255.

I was wondering if there's a shorter way of writing this regex, such that `pattern` only has to be written once, while not compromising the accuracy of the regex, like `(pattern\.?){4}` does.

*edit*

Looks like this: `^pattern($|\.(?!$)){4}$` does exactly what I'm looking for.

Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28446132/4526483

Comment: your regex accepts 00, but not 000. why?

Comment: I don't think I've seen anyone write an IP address with multi-digit zeros in any of the octels

Comment: Doesn't mean it's not valid though.

Comment: I suppose if you really were expecting them, you could use `(0|1)?\d?\d` instead of `1?\d?\d`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression for IP Address Validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006459/regular-expression-for-ip-address-validation)

Comment: IP address validation is very complex subject and is next to impossible to cover in one regex.  Please see this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4

Comment: Specifically, sounds like you're looking for this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28445732/1255289

Comment: Assuming the pattern was just `4` then `'^(4((?=$)|.(?!$))){4}$'` matches the start of a string, 4 at the end of the string or a dot which isn't at the end, four times, then the end of string. Because I don't think it's possible to match the end of string more than once, this seems to constrain it to `4.4.4.4` precisely. Your pattern is different, your regex engine might not support lookarounds. Ymmv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually yes! Start with a slightly too-flexible regex that has complex pattern once:

```
(pattern\.?){4}
```

Then apply an assertion to lock down the dots:

```
(?=(\d+\.){3}\d+([^.\d]|$))(pattern\.?){4}
```

The full regex would then be:

```
(?=(\d+\.){3}\d+([^.\d]|$)(1?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){4}
```

---

If a dot is OK to immediately follow the ip, remove the dot from the character class in the look ahead.

Comment: Looks like that does make it a little bit shorter:

`(?=(\\d+\.){3}\\d+)((1?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.?){4}`

Comment: @knowbody if you're not fussy about what follows you can even delete entirely the final part `([^.\d]|$)`