# How to validate if IP address is correct?

Tags: javascript, ip

I am creating snmp session everything is working as expected , i will be getting dynamic value of `host` to create session, I just want to put if condition to check Ip address is correct or not , is there way to validate IP address in javascript ?

main.js

```
var host = "135.01.01.01";
var sessionOptions = {
    port: 161,
    retries: 1,
    timeout: 5000,
    transport: "udp4",
    trapPort: msg.event.body.trapPort,
    version: snmpVersion
};
//Create snmp Session
var session = snmp.createSession(host, "public", sessionOptions);

try {
    if (!host) {
        console.log("Could not find host");
    } else {
        session.trap(trapOid, varbinds, options, function(error) {
            if (error)
                console.log(error);
            else
                console.log('SNMP successfully delivered');
        });
    }
} catch (e) {
    console.log("SNMP processing error: " + e);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"? As in, is it formatted correctly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006459/regular-expression-for-ip-address-validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted from [here](http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/ip-address-validation.php):

```
function ValidateIPaddress(ipaddress)   
{  
 if (/^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/.test(host))  
  {  
    return (true)  
  }  
return (false)  
}
```