# Java script regular Expression for IP Address validation

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation

Can some one help me whether my java script code for IP Address validation is correct or not? I am  using a regular expression that does not allow any other special characters other than dot and also does not allow non-numeric characters.I am trying to validate IP Address in web page, loaded in our Modem.IP address is not getting validated when web page is loaded in modem.Please find code snippet and help me in resolving this issue...

```
       function chkIPV4()
       {
          for(x=0;x<txtBox.length;x++)
          {
               var ip4add = document.getElementById(txtBox[x]).value;
               var name=txtBox[x];
               var chk_arr = ip4add.split(".");
               if(chk_arr.length != 4)
               {
                  alert(name +" is not Valid");
                  return false;
               }
               for(var i=0; i < chk_arr.length; i++)
               { 
                   if( !(/^\d+$/.test(chk_arr[i])))
                   {
                     alert(name +" is not Valid");
                      return false;
                   }
                   else if( chk_arr[i] < 0 || chk_arr[i] > 255)
                  {
                     alert(name +" is not Valid");
                     return false;
                   }
            }

     } 
     return true;}
```

Comment: [Refer this link.Hope it works.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006459/regular-expression-for-ip-address-validation)

Comment: I want to know whether my code has an issue...so that I can resolve it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belong to [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: If I use isNaN then it doesn't allow dot also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var length= document.getElementById("txtBox").value.length;
```

Check your array value that seems error.