# Why does this regexp for IPv4 doesn't work?

Tags: regex, pcre

So this is the regex I've made:
`^(([01]?\d{1,2})|(2(([0-4]\d)|(5[0-5])))\.){3}(([01]?\d{1,2})|(2(([0-4]\d)|(5[0-5]))))$`

I have used several sites to break it down and it seems that it should work, but it doesn't. The desired result is to match any IPv4 - four numbers between 0 and 255 delimited by dots.

As an example, `1.1.1.1` won't give you a match.
The purpose of this question is not to find out a regex for IPv4 address, but to find out why this one, which seems correct, is not.

Comment: Can you give an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: @ndn added an example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression for IP Address Validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006459/regular-expression-for-ip-address-validation)

Comment: take out the `^` and the `$` start and end of line anchors for starters...

Comment: @SebastianProske I'm not asking for a regex for IP, I'm asking why this one won't work.

Comment: @sweaver2112 - Those are required, otherwise you could match `999127.0.0.1012345` because no start/end anchoring has been applied.

Comment: @AndrewVershinin because the way you arranged groups and alternations is wrong.

Comment: The tl;dr answer is that the brackets are messed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The literal `.` is only part of the 200-255 section of the capture group: [railroad diagram](https://regexper.com/#%5E((%5B01%5D%3F%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D)%7C(2(%5B0-4%5D%5Cd)%7C(5%5B0-5%5D))%5C.)%7B3%7D((%5B01%5D%3F%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D)%7C(2(%5B0-4%5D%5Cd)%7C(5%5B0-5%5D)))%24).

Here's `(([01]?\d{1,2})|(2([0-4]\d)|(5[0-5]))\.)` formatted differently to help you spot the reason:

```
(
    ([01]?\d{1,2})
    |
    (2([0-4]\d)|(5[0-5])) \.
)
```

You're matching 0-199 **or** 200-255 with a dot.  The dot is conditional on matching 200-255.

Additionally, as @SebastianProske pointed out, `2([0-4]\d)|(5[0-5])` matches 200-249 **or** 50-55, not 200-255.

You can fix your regex by adding capturing groups, but ultimately I would recommend not reinventing the wheel and using A) a pre-existing regex solution or B) parse the IPv4 address by splitting on dots.  The latter method being easier to read and understand.

Comment: There is no 200-255 section, it's a 200-249 and 50-55 section.

Comment: @SebastianProske - Oof, that'll need fixing too.  I'll edit that in.

Comment: @SebastianProske I have corrected the expression. I've enclosed the OR clause in a group, but it doesn't makes the expression to match correctly.

Comment: @AndrewVershinin - You'll need to add a group to fix the 200-255 issue as well as add a group to fix the dot issue.  You'll need to fix the 200-255 issue in both places it appears.

Comment: @Mr.Llama Thank you. Enclosing the part before the dot makes it work. As the question states, I can use Google. I just wanted to realise why this solution is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

to fix yours up, just account for the "decimal" after *each of the first three* groups:

```
((2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|[01]?\d{1,2})\.){3}(2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|[01]?\d{1,2})
```

(*note that I reversed the order of the *2xx vs 1xx* tests as well - prefer `SPECIAL|...|NORMAL`, or more restrictive first, when using alternations like this)

[see it in action](https://regex101.com/r/JCe0cW/1)