# How to validate an ip address with custom format using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate an ip address with custom format:

Format i expected :
`ip address - any value - anynumber`

Format above have 4 parts:

1. ip address (contain a valid ip address)
2. any value (contain any value)
3. any number (contain only 1 to 3 digits of number)
4. connecting parts (contain space,dash,space `( - )`)

Example : `213.39.59.78 - Public3 address.info - 24`

```js
function customFormat(val) {
  return /^(?=\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$)(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.?){4}$/.test(val);
}
var testFormat = '192.68.35.35';
document.getElementById('regex').innerHTML += testFormat + ' ' + (customFormat(testFormat) ? 'Valid Format!' : 'Invalid Format!');
```

```html
<ul id="regex"></ul>
```

Code above used regular expression from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26671130/9289169), but just validate the ip address.

How to validate an ip address like format i expected?

Comment: You need to add something like ` - [^-]+- \d+` before the final *$* in the RegExp, but I think doing this with a regular expression results in very obfuscated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something you could try:

```js
function customFormat(val) {
  return /^(?=\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.?){4} - ((?! -).)+ - \d{1,3}$/.test(val);
}
var testFormat = '213.39.59.78 - Public3 address.info - 24';
document.getElementById('regex').innerHTML += testFormat + ' ' + (customFormat(testFormat) ? 'Valid Format!' : 'Invalid Format!');
```

```html
<ul id="regex"></ul>
```

#### Breakdown:

Regex:

```
/^(?=\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.?){4} - ((?! -).)+ - \d{1,3}$/
```

The regex has 5 parts that are pretty much the parts you listed:

1. `/^`

   - Matches the beginning of string
2. `(?=\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.?){4}`

   - ip address (contain a valid ip address)
3. `-`

   - connecting parts (contain space,dash,space `( - )`)
4. `((?! -).)+`

   - any value (contain any value)
   - **important:** this part uses a lookahead and matches one or more chars that are not the connecting part. In other words, it will match anything until it finds a `-`.
5. `-`

   - connecting parts (contain space,dash,space `( - )`)
6. `\d{1,3}`

   - any number (contain only 1 to 3 digits of number)
7. `$/`

   - End of string.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works and your explanation is very clear

Answer (score 0):

[image]Try this...
It works for me

```
function ValidateIPaddress(ipaddress) 
{
 if (/^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/.test(myForm.emailAddr.value))
  {
    return (true)
  }
  alert("You have entered an invalid IP address!")
  return (false)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

By parsing the string and testing each part you'll get easier to follow code and the ability to return errors based on what went wrong if it fails the tests, e.g.:

```js
function checkIP(s) {
  var t = s.split(' - ');

  // Test number of parts
  if (t.length != 3)
    return 'Error: format must be <IP address> - <string, no "-"> - <1 to 3 digits>: ' + s;

  // Test IP address
  if (!t[0].split('.').every(v => v >= 0 && v <= 255))
    return 'Error: IP address is invalid: ' + t[0];

  // Test trailing number
  if (!/^\d{1,3}$/.test(t[2])) 
    return 'Error: String must end with 1 to 3 digits: ' + t[2];

  // Must be valid
  return 'Valid string';
}

// Some tests
['213.39.59.78 - Public3 address.info - 222',
 '213.39.59.78 - Public3 address.info - 2222',
 '213.39.59.78 - Public3 address.info',
 '213.39.59.788 - Public3 address.info - 222'
].forEach(s => console.log(`Testing "${s}"\n ${checkIP(s)}`));
```

You might want to throw errors instead of just returning a string with an error message.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

function **ValidateIPaddress**(ipaddress) {
  if (/^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/.test(ipaddress)) {
    return (true)
  }
  alert("You have entered an invalid IP address!")
  return (false)
}

Comment: Code-only answers aren't helpful.

Comment: Please add the description or steps for this answer to make it helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.