# What to add to a regex IPv4 Validation to also validate CIDR IPv4?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have two function in JS that check if a typed input is a valid IPv4.
This is the regex that I got from **@Abana Clara** from this question: [How to validate IP Address on multiple inputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56932299/how-to-validate-ip-address-on-multiple-inputs)

```
var ipformat = /^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/;
```

I would like to add to this regex the possibility to also validate CIDR IPv4 addresses.

Please note that both of the following addresses should be valid:

```
192.168.1.20
192.168.1.20/24
```

Comment: In the linked solution, replace the colon with an escaped slash.

Comment: But that doesn't look like my regex. It's far from it. I only want to add to that regex, not replace my whole script.

Comment: So add `\/[0-9]{1,3}` before `$`...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that validates `192.168.1.20/24` but invalidates `192.168.1.20`

Comment: Then make it optional - `(?:\/[0-9]{1,3})?`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew And do you know where to place 32 inside that thing so that 32 be the max value ?

Comment: Use http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/ to get such patterns. If you want 0 to 32, `(?:\/(?:[0-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0-2]))?`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you very much. I have done it like this: `(?:\/([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))?`

Comment: Yeah, a tiny overhead won't hurt here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I hoped that you understood how bad I am at this. I don't know what is the overhead, how does it look, where to put or why.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31500422/are-non-capturing-groups-redundant